# unable to upgrade

Tags: apt

Whenever I try to upgrade on raspbian it says, `"E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?`

Nothing I have tried yet works. It also was like this when I used Ubuntu and Manjaro.

Thanks in advance for any solutions

Comment: Hello and welcome -- Add what exactly you have tried to solve the problem.

Comment: Try running `sudo apt update` (the more modern command than `sudo apt-get update`). Then run`sudo apt dist-upgrade -y` to try again.

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking a question like this "Should I upgrade if I found anything interesting?" or this "Should I be the first user?" My answer is yes, and no, it all depends how are your engineering trade off or business cost benefit analysis. I am a die hard Winows guy, and I have only used serious Raspbian for about 5 hobbyist years.  I think I have spent perhaps 100+ hours in end-up-failure upgrades, each "wasting" 3+ hours.  Yes, they all ended up failures, but then I learnt many linux tricks that I-didn't-know-that-I-didn't-know. So I see all of them good learning experiences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a common problem with Linux users.

Remove content of `/var/lib/apt/lists` directory by:

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

then run it:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

And:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for that. Although after I downloaded chrome 64 bit for deb, I tried to install it using terminal, it came up with this error, if you have any solutions to that too it would be extremely helpful.  pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
dpkg: error processing archive google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb (--install):
 package architecture (amd64) does not match system (armhf)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb

Comment: @BalboBiggans That should be asked as a separate question, thanks: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/108646/5538

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem when upgrading

You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgeotiff2 : Depends: libproj13 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not installed
libogdi3.2 : Depends: libproj13 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not installed
libspatialite7 : Depends: libproj13 (>= 4.8.0) but it is not installed
proj-bin : Depends: libproj13 (>= 5.0.0) but it is not installed
python-gdal : Depends: gdal-abi-2-4-0
Depends: libgdal20 (>= 2.4.0) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).